# Apache server response timeout

Tags: web-services, apache, httpresponse

So I am trying to use a web service on my Apache server and when I send a request to the service. I should be receiving about 9,000 items packed in xml format with multiple properties for each.

The problem I believe is when make this request, it takes so long to process the response that the server times out the request and I never receive anything. when making a request for about 1000 items it takes about 7 seconds. I believe there is a limit to 60 seconds somewhere in the server as 9000 if linear would be about 63 seconds which is just past this 1 minute limit.

Anyone got an idea on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try bumping up the connectionTimeout parameter to a higher number. Its set to 60 seconds by default.

Comment: Where is this file at? application.config? I don't know where to put this setting at is the main problem..

Comment: connectionTimeout is for tomcat - my bad. For Apache it should be the Timeout directive in the httpd.conf file